# How to use plain javascript to delete with confirm in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I don't have jquery_ujs in my project, So I am trying to get a pop up when clicked on a delete button.

But the item is getting deleted, even if I press cancel or ok.

Here is the code:

```
= button_to "Remove Item", item, method: :delete, onclick: 'remove_item()'

function remove_item(event){
    if (!confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the item')) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Can you help me solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `event` in the onclick attribute, actually you're just using the function without passing the argument, try with:

```
= button_to "Remove Item", item, method: :delete, onclick: 'remove_item(event)'
```